# QDirIterator - No hasNext not FilePath reaction

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

What I want to do is that it give me a list with all .cpp files in the Directory and the Subdirectories. Problem *it.HasNext* stay on false and also *it.filePath* stay empty.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "QtSignal_Slot.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtSignal_Slot w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**ui_QtSignal_Slot.h**

```
#ifndef UI_QTSIGNAL_SLOT_H
#define UI_QTSIGNAL_SLOT_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_QtSignal_SlotClass
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QPushButton *ButtonStart;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_2;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_4;
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_2;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_3;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;
    QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer_3;
    QLineEdit *PathEdit;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *QtSignal_SlotClass)
    {
        if (QtSignal_SlotClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            QtSignal_SlotClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("QtSignal_SlotClass"));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setEnabled(true);
        QtSignal_SlotClass->resize(380, 250);
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(QtSignal_SlotClass->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setMinimumSize(QSize(380, 250));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setMaximumSize(QSize(700, 300));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setSizeIncrement(QSize(400, 250));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setBaseSize(QSize(200, 250));
        centralWidget = new QWidget(QtSignal_SlotClass);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(centralWidget);
        gridLayout->setSpacing(6);
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayout"));
        ButtonStart = new QPushButton(centralWidget);
        ButtonStart->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("ButtonStart"));
        ButtonStart->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("background-color: rgb(200,200,255); color: rgb(0,0,0);"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(ButtonStart, 7, 1, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer_2, 7, 2, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer_4 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer_4, 0, 2, 1, 1);

        textEdit = new QTextEdit(centralWidget);
        textEdit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textEdit"));
        textEdit->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("color: rgb(0,0,0);"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(textEdit, 3, 1, 1, 1);

        verticalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        gridLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_2, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        verticalSpacer_3 = new QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        gridLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_3, 2, 1, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer, 7, 0, 1, 1);

        horizontalSpacer_3 = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        gridLayout->addItem(horizontalSpacer_3, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        PathEdit = new QLineEdit(centralWidget);
        PathEdit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("PathEdit"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy1(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(PathEdit->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        PathEdit->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
        PathEdit->setMinimumSize(QSize(200, 30));
        PathEdit->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("background-color: rgb(240,240,240); color: rgb(0,0,0);"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(PathEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        QtSignal_SlotClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(QtSignal_SlotClass);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 380, 21));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(QtSignal_SlotClass);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("mainToolBar"));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(QtSignal_SlotClass);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("statusBar"));
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        retranslateUi(QtSignal_SlotClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QtSignal_SlotClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *QtSignal_SlotClass)
    {
        QtSignal_SlotClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("QtSignal_SlotClass", "QtSignal_Slot", Q_NULLPTR));
        ButtonStart->setText(QApplication::translate("QtSignal_SlotClass", "Generate graphicfile", Q_NULLPTR));
        PathEdit->setText(QString());
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class QtSignal_SlotClass: public Ui_QtSignal_SlotClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_QTSIGNAL_SLOT_H
```

**QtSignal_Slot.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtSignal_Slot.h"

class QtSignal_Slot : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QString m_Path;

    QtSignal_Slot(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

public slots:
    void m_StartButtonpressed();

private:
    Ui::QtSignal_SlotClass ui;
};
```

**QtSolts_Signel.cpp**

```
#include "QtSignal_Slot.h"
#include <ui_QtSignal_Slot.h>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QDebug>

QtSignal_Slot::QtSignal_Slot(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(nullptr)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.ButtonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(m_StartButtonpressed()));
}

void QtSignal_Slot::m_StartButton()
{
    m_Path = (ui.PathEdit->text());

    QDirIterator it(m_Path, QStringList() << "*.cpp" , QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    do
    {
        qDebug() << it.next();

    } while (it.hasNext());

    qDebug() << "This, show in the Output";
    QString Buffer = QString("%1").arg(QString::number(it.hasNext()));
    ui.textEdit->setText(Buffer +"->" + it.filePath() + "<-" + m_Path);
}
```

The output in the textEdit is:

> "0-> <-(correct path i but i as input)"

and output in the debug-output is:

> " ' ' , This, show in the Output"

The code is updated, but the problem stays.

Comment: If the loop has exited then obviously `hasNext` is false (otherwise the loop would have continue to run). So calling `it.next` after the loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok to remove the it.next just remove one ' ' from the debug-output but the programm is still not working

Comment: Please take some time to rewrite and update your question. Information from the comments will be hard to track for other people who might answer your question. Please do not put "EDIT" headers - just rewrite the parts that are outdated so the question will show the code as it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Example

Here is an example of how to make the slot work:

*MainWindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QLineEdit;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QLineEdit *m_pathEdit;
    QLineEdit *m_textEdit;

private slots:
    void onButtonClicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*MainWindow.cpp*

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_pathEdit(new QLineEdit(this)),
    m_textEdit(new QLineEdit(this))
{
    auto *widget = new QWidget(this);
    auto *layoutMain = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    auto *button = new QPushButton(tr("Click me"), this);

    layoutMain->addWidget(m_pathEdit);
    layoutMain->addWidget(m_textEdit);
    layoutMain->addWidget(button);

    setCentralWidget(widget);

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonClicked);
}

void MainWindow::onButtonClicked()
{
    const QString &path(m_pathEdit->text());
    QDirIterator it(path, QStringList() << "*.cpp" , QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    do
    {
        qDebug() << it.next();

    } while (it.hasNext());

    qDebug() << "This, show in the Output";

    QString buffer(QString("%1").arg(QString::number(it.hasNext())));

    m_textEdit->setText(buffer +"->" + it.filePath() + "<-" + path);
}
```

## Result

For the following input (entered in `m_pathEdit`, the upper `QLineEdit`):

> /Users/Michael Scopchanov/Desktop/untitled9/

the result in the console is:

```
"/Users/Michael Scopchanov/Desktop/untitled9/main.cpp"
"/Users/Michael Scopchanov/Desktop/untitled9/MainWindow.cpp"
"/Users/Michael Scopchanov/Desktop/untitled9/MyLabel.cpp"
This, show in the Output
```

and the text of `m_textEdit` is set to:

> 0->/Users/Michael Scopchanov/Desktop/untitled9/MyLabel.cpp<-/Users/Michael Scopchanov/Desktop/untitled9/

Comment: it looks very good thank you.  sadly i copyd the *onButtonClicked* function and 
replaced *const QString &path(m_pathEdit->text());* by   *const QString &path(ui.PathEdit->text());* buuut it still not work and th aoutput is complet emty

Comment: @Kaneros, I suggest you to test the code as it is given. It works. Then compare it to your code, see what you are doing differently and you might be able to find the reason. Furthermore, provide more details about your project, in order to help you in the search. Also, if you find the answer useful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: the problem with copy paste your hole code is that i work with QtDesigner to create the Gui thats why i just copied you function. the reson why i repaced m_pathedit is a consequence of this.

Comment: @Kaneros, I understand that. That is why I am suggesting you to show the relevant parts of your project in order to be possible to help you with your search.

Comment: I updated the first part with all my code sorry for the mess in the ui file its autogenerated from Qt. thank you for your help

Comment: @Kaneros, what do you type in `m_pathEdit` before pressing `ButtonStart`?

Comment: *C:\Users\lbuchser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\QtSignal_Slot* the path where the first file of the program is. is this the mistake?

Comment: Try to make the back slashes \ forward slashes /.

Comment: also tryed but still no result